# Create video demo of ipad application

Tags: screen-capture, ipad, simulation

How would I go about creating a demo video of an ipad application (in the ipad simulator)?
The video should preferably use a circle as the cursor and also
support moving between portrait/landscape modes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a screen capture utility like Snapz Pro, or if you're running Snow Leopard you can just use Quicktime X screen capture facilities. I also use a free app PhoneFinger - http://www.wonderwarp.com/phonefinger/ - which changes the look of the mouse cursor. The fault is a finger which is quite tacky, but in the preferences you can change this to a semi-transparent circle which gets bigger on mousedown... You've probably seen other demos which use similar.

There are a few caveats using this method for demonstrating iPad apps. Firstly, if you're capturing using Quicktime X then you'll need some post-production video editing software to crop off all the surrounding screen information so it doesn't look like a simulator. Secondly, the simulator itself... Doesn't look exactly like an iPad! The border around it is a fair bit thinner (I guess they did this to save on screen space), so you may need further post-production work altering this. And finally, if your app involves any multi-touch gestures, the simulator only provides you with the ability to pinch or rotate from the centre of the iPad screen.

If anyone has any hints or tips on these three things, I'd be very interested in finding out more, thanks!

:-Joe

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Snapz Pro (which, while great, is also $69) is to use [Capture Me](http://www.chimoosoft.com/products/captureme/).

It's rather old utility (but still works well), and unlike quicktime this program can easily capture only part of the screen.

Together with [Phonefinger](http://www.wonderwarp.com/phonefinger/), you can make decent demo video's for free with little effort.